# Not catching click events on links with role of button in jquery mobile 1.8.2 + Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery

I have reshaped two links to small round buttons, however for some reason I am not able to catch their click-events with any of the approaches that you can see in [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/y7dxW/1/)

Any help would be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made several mistakes in your JS code.

**1 -** You forgot a `$` and a `.`:

Instead of:

```
('ui-input-clear').on('click', function() {
    alert('!');
});
```

you should have:

```
$('.ui-input-clear').on('click', function() {
    alert('!');
});
```

**2 -** Also, replace:

```
$document.ready(function() {
```

with:

```
$(function() {
```

Then, it should work.

**Note:** It is very useful to check your console for tracking JS errors. You can try Firebug if you haven't discovered it yet! (I love Firebug! :P XD )

Comment: Silly me! Tnx for your advice! Just one thing: why you want me to remove document.ready() with just a function()? I am trying to wait for DOM to load up!Also I guess you no longer need Firebug as you have built-in features in web-kit based browsers. Am i wrong?

Comment: Hey mate :) ! yes you can use `document.ready()`. It's just that I usually use `$(function` instead ^^. And yes you have web-kit tools integrated in browsers, but I feel like Firebug is more convenient (I used it for a long time so I may got used to it). It may be a question of preference, though you may have a try and delete it if you do not like it :)